# How I can specify a branch of my library's repo generated by git-flow as composer requirement

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

In my team's projects need a common library where I place common logic in it. Therefore, according to teams flow I cloned the library repo (assuming hosted upon `myteam/mylibrary.git` repo in github):

```
git clone git@github.com:myteam/mylibrary.git
```

And in order to apply my changes on the library I run the following command cocktail:

```
git flow feature start mychanges
# Developing changeds
git commit -m "Applying my changed"
git push origin feature/mychanges
```

Then I need to test the library changes on each project that will consume the library's change. Therefore I tried the to change the following on `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require":{
     ...,
     'myteam/mylibrary':'dev-feature/mychanges'
   },
   "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@github.com:myteam/mylibrary.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I run the following command:

```
composer update myteam/mylibrary
```

But I got the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package myteam/mylibrary could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Do you know how I can fix that?

Same result I get if I change my `composer.json` into:

```
{
  "require":{
     ...,
     'myteam/mylibrary':'dev-master'
   },
   "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@github.com:myteam/mylibrary.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you install it on `dev-master`?

Comment: Nope I cannot install it on `dev-master` as well.

Comment: So the problem is not really gitflow created branches, but simply install anything from the git repository.

Comment: Have you tried `composer require myteam/mylibrary:dev-master`?